# Retornar 2 valores de store precedure hacia c#

Tags: c#, sql

Buen dia

Tengo una aplicacion de tickets (Soporte Tecnico) el cual ingresa la informacion hacia mi tabla en SQL SERVER , la logica es que uno de los campos es el correo electronico del usuario, si existe en mi store procedure entonces realiza la insercion de datos, si no existe manda un mensaje.

Tambien cuando se genera un nuevo # de ticket mi codigo creara una carpeta con el nombre del # de ticket. Al ejecutar dos veces el Execute Scalalar, mi store se ejecuta dos veces tambien, duplicando la informacion. ¿Como puedo ejecutar una ves el store y obtener el idcas para poder crear mi carpeta con este nombre?

```
    int correo = 0;
            int idcas = 0;
            string txtidcas;
            string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_casportal"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correo", txtcorreo.Text.Trim());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titulo", txttituloproblema.Text.Trim());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@problema", txtproblema.Text.Trim());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoriacas", ddlcategoria.SelectedValue);
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        correo = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                        idcas = (int)(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                        txtidcas = idcas.ToString();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    switch (correo)
                    {
                        case -1:
                            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
                            Response.Write("alert('Error: Correo no existe');");
                            Response.Write("document.location.href='agregarimpresora.aspx';");
                            Response.Write("</script>");
                            break;

                        default:
                            //obtenemos el nombre del directorio
                            string directorio = $"C:\\CAS\\{txtidcas}";
                            //Creamos la carpeta con con el nombre # de CAS
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(directorio);



                            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
                                Response.Write("alert('Ticket generado con Exito, se envio un correo con la informacion');");
                                Response.Write("document.location.href='cas_portal.aspx';");
                                Response.Write("</script>");
                            break;
                    }
                }




@correo VARCHAR(30),
@titulo VARCHAR(30),
@problema VARCHAR(100),
@categoriacas INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idempleado INT
    DECLARE @idcas INT
    SELECT @idempleado = idempleado FROM tbl_empleado WHERE correo = @correo

    if @idempleado IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_cas(correo,titulo,problema,fecha,idempleado,idestatus,idcategoria)
            VALUES (@correo,@titulo,@problema, GetDate(), @idempleado, 1, @categoriacas)

            SELECT @idcas = MAX(idcas) FROM tbl_cas
            SELECT @idcas [idcas] -- pasa el valor del ultima idcas hacia c#
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT - 1 --Correo no encontrado
        END
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada, el título indica que quieres obtener dos valores sin embargo en tu explicación solamente pides por un valor:

> ¿Como puedo ejecutar una ves el store y obtener el idcas para poder crear mi carpeta con este nombre?

En tu SP parece ser que si no existe el correo entonces regresa -1 y si sí existe entonces regresa idcas, nunca regresa nada sobre el correo. Tomando esto como base, solo tendrías que ejecutar el comando una sola vez y asignarlo a idcas (convirtiéndolo a entero) si la inserción fue correcta idcas será diferente de -1 y podrás tomar a txtcorreo.Text.Trim() como un valor válido.

```
...

con.Open();
idcas = (int)(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
txtidcas = idcas.ToString();

con.Close();

}

switch (idcas)
{
  // tú código
}
```

Supongo que ya lo has tomado en cuenta pero no olvides poner un try - catch para que controles cuando exista un error en la conexión.

Comment: Gracias carlos por las observaciones, el correo lo regreso con un -1 en caso de que no exista para que no ingrese los datos, el idcas lo necesito para crear una carpeta con ese nombre, el swtch(idcas) no me funciona por que lo que valido con el switch es el correo, solo necesito guardar el idcas en una variable tipo string para poder proceder a crear la carpeta

Comment: Pero en tu SP regresas -1 o idcas. Es decir que si asignas lo que regresa tu SP a idcas obtendrás -1 o el nuevo valor idcas que se ingresó. Si haces switch(idcas), en el caso de que idcas = -1 quiere decir que no existió correo y si es diferente a -1 quiere decir que sí existió. O sea, con idcas es suficiente para saber si existió correo o no, y si sí existió, cuál es el valor del nuevo idcas.

Comment: Es que necesito realizar primero el insert para poder generar el nuevo id (el ultimo), despues obtener el idcas para poder crear la carpeta con este nombre, no valido nada con idcas, solo requiero guadaralo en una variable string para obtener el nombre de la carpeta (convertirlo a string previo)

Comment: Hay dos casos: el primero sería que se entre al SP y no exista el correo por lo que no se ingresa nada a la BD y el SP regresa -1. Ese valor se asigna a la variable idcas en C#, después entras al switch en el caso -1, entonces se manda un mensaje de error (tal como lo tienes en tu switch). El segundo caso es que sí se ingrese un registro, entonces el SP regresa el id que se ingresó y en C# es asignado a la variable idcas. Como idcas != -1, en el switch entrarás al default y ahí se usará txtidcas para generar tu carpeta. Todos los casos están cubiertos a excepción de un error de conexión.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolverlo con algo de ayuda, agrege un parametro en mi codigo de tipo OUTPUT igual en mi sotre para que lo recibiera, le agrege un OUTPUT de SCOPE_IDENTITY ya que lo que necesitaba era el ultimo ID. Aunque no se realmente si necesito ese Return del final

```
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correo", txtcorreo.Text.Trim());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titulo", txttituloproblema.Text.Trim());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@problema", txtproblema.Text.Trim());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoriacas", ddlcategoria.SelectedValue);

                        //Parametro que recibira el OUTPUT
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@idcas", SqlDbType.Char, 500);
                        cmd.Parameters["@idcas"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        correo = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                        //Asigno el OUTPUT a variable tipo string
                        txtidcas = (string)cmd.Parameters["@idcas"].Value; 
                        con.Close();
                    }





    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_casportal]
@correo VARCHAR(30),
@titulo VARCHAR(30),
@problema VARCHAR(100),
@categoriacas INT,
@idcas INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idempleado INT
    SELECT @idempleado = idempleado FROM tbl_empleado WHERE correo = @correo

    if @idempleado IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_cas(correo,titulo,problema,fecha,idempleado,idestatus,idcategoria)
            VALUES (@correo,@titulo,@problema, GetDate(), @idempleado, 1, @categoriacas)

            SELECT @idcas = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT - 1 --Correo no encontrado
        END
        Return @idcas
    END
GO
```